# Setting label value from OptionMenu in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, optionmenu

I would like to set a label value to the value of the current optionmenu value. If the latter changes I want the former to change too. My issue is that this gui elements are defined in separate classes (and I want them to be like that), but I do not know how to connect them together. Without classes I know I can use the `OptionMenu`'s `command` method to set the value of the `Label`. But putting them into Frame containers I am stuck.
Here is a simplistic and functioning code what I want to resolve:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
opt=['Jan', 'Feb', 'March']

class MyOptMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.var = StringVar(self)
        self.var.set(opt[0])
        self.om = OptionMenu(self, self.var, *opt)
        self.om.pack(side=TOP)
        self.var.trace('w', self.getValue)
   def getValue(self, *args):
        return(self.var.get())

class MyLabel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.labstring = StringVar(self)
        self.lab = Label(self, textvariable = self.labstring, bg='white')
        self.lab.pack(side=TOP)
        self.labstring.set('hello')

a = MyOptMenu(root)
b = MyLabel(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Could you give me some help how to proceed. Many thanks.

Comment: The easiest way would be for your label to have the same `StringVar` than the optionmenu. Do you really need to define one `StringVar` for each?

Comment: Hmm, actually that is very clever :) For some reason I did not think about that. I made the changes and it works. Many thanks.

Comment: @KiralySandor Please provide the answer if you've resolved the issue.

Comment: @Nae, I added an answer with the solution that worked for me and added comments to it, to explain the changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to @j_4321's suggestion, here I post the solution that resolved my issue. I provide explanation in comments in between code lines.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
opt=['Jan', 'Feb', 'March']

var = StringVar(root)  # initialization of a common StringVar for both OptionMenu and Label widgets

class MyOptMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        var.set(opt[0])  # give an initial value to the StringVar that will be displayed first on the OptionMenu
        self.om = OptionMenu(self, var, *opt)
        self.om.pack(side=TOP)
        var.trace('w', self.getValue)   # continuously trace the value of the selected items in the OptionMenu and update the var variable, using the function self.getValue
    def getValue(self, *args):
        return(var.get())  # return the current value of OptionMenu

class MyLabel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.lab = Label(self, textvariable = var, bg='white')  # use the same StringVar variable (var) as the OptionMenu. This allows changing the Label text instantaneously to the selected value of OptionMenu
        self.lab.pack(side=TOP)

a = MyOptMenu(root)
b = MyLabel(root)
root.mainloop()
```